# What is the worst-case time and space complexity of a uniform-cost search algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

My book here (Artificial intelligence A modern approach) says that the worst-case time and space complexity of a uniform-cost search algorithm would be  **O(b[C*/e])**  , where *b* is the branching factor, *C** is the cost of the optimal solution, and every action costs atleast *e*. But why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the complexity is **`O(B^(C/e))`** [exponential in `C/e`].

To understand it, think of a simple example case first:

Let `G=(V,E)` be a graph, with branch factor `B`. The graph is unweighted (`w(e) = 1` for each `e`).

Consider finding the shortest path from S to T.

In this case, the algorithm is actually a **BFS**, and it will discover all nodes in the path up to length `SOL`, where `SOL` is the length of the shortest path, which is `O(B^|SOL|)`

For the general case - the same idea holds, you need to discover all nodes up to cost `C`. So you discover nodes up to depth `C/e`, giving you **`O(B^(C/e))`** total nodes needed to be explored.

The exponential factor is because: First level (root) has `B^0=1` nodes, second level has B nodes. from each of these you discover `B` nodes, giving you `B^2`, ....

---

**EDIT:** 

Missed it so far, but the title asks for *space complexity* and not *time complexity*. However, the answer remains the same, since a uniform cost search holds a `visited` set, for already visited nodes. Since each node you discover is also added to it - the answer remains `O(B^(C/e))`

Comment: But why do you take `C/e` ? **C** is the cost of the the goal, and **e** is the minimum cost of any node. So what's the logic behind this.

Comment: @Ghost: `C/e` is the maximal possible depth you need to traverse. If the goal cost is `C`, and each edge cost at least `e`, the total number of edges you can traverse in each path is at most `C/e`

Comment: So is `C*` the cost of traversing from the root to the goal node, or the cost of traversing from the node before the goal to the goal node?

Comment: @Ghost: From the source to the goal (The sum of costs of all edges on the path leading from source to goal)

Comment: the reason it is to the power **C/e** because if assuming the ideal cost to the goal is **C**, remember uniform cost search only works if the difference in cost for each step is at least **e**, so the number of steps to the goal **C** will **C/e** hence **O(B^(C/e))**

Answer (score 1):

`C*/e` means average number of nodes which should be visited during the search, and for visiting each of this nodes you should look at all possible `b` branches (at least root nodes), so you should check b<sup>[C*/e]</sup> node in your search. which is your search time complexity, this is by assuming process on each node takes O(1).

<sub>P.S: It's Ω(b<sup>[C*/e]</sup>)in worst case</sub>